# Stuck within program - New to Swing in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm brand spanking new to Swing in Java as I am more familiar with JavaFX. However, my professor wants me to use Swing for an assignment.

I'm a bit stupefied at the moment, because for some reason, my method to add and append to a TextArea in swing is not working. I'm getting a runtime error upon clicking the add button button within my Application. Runtime error is the following:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PlantGUIDriverFinalAssignment.addFlower(PlantGUIDriverFinalAssignment.java:170)
    at PlantGUIDriverFinalAssignment.access$100(PlantGUIDriverFinalAssignment.java:11)
    at PlantGUIDriverFinalAssignment$ButtonHandlerAdd.actionPerformed(PlantGUIDriverFinalAssignment.java:326)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Thus far, I can't add an instance of my plant Object or subclass Flower to the text area because of the runtime Error. Here is the GUI code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PlantGUIDriverFinalAssignment extends JFrame {
        JRadioButton rdoBtnPlant, rdoBtnFlower, rdoBtnHerb, rdoBtnWeed, rdoBtnFungus;
        JCheckBox isPoisonous, isEdible, isMedicinal, isNicelyFlavored, isSeasonal, hasThorns, smellsNice;
        JButton btnAdd, btnRemove, btnFilter, btnClear, btnSort;
        JTextField txtPlantID, txtColor, txtName;
        JScrollPane scrollPane;
        JTextArea plantSummary;
        String plantColor, plantName, plantID;
        ArrayList<Plant> plantList;

    public PlantGUIDriverFinalAssignment() {
            try {
                this.setTitle("Plant Interface");
                setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                JPanel plantPanel1 = new JPanel(); //Create a Pane to add components within them to better organize the UI
                JPanel plantPanel2 = new JPanel(); //Create another Panel to hold more plant components (checkboxes, etc)
                JPanel plantPanel3 = new JPanel(); //Create this panel to hold buttons.
                JPanel plantPanel4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); //Create this Panel to hold TextArea plantSummary

                rdoBtnPlant = new JRadioButton("Plant");
                rdoBtnFlower = new JRadioButton("Flower");
                rdoBtnWeed = new JRadioButton("Weed");
                rdoBtnHerb = new JRadioButton("Herb");
                rdoBtnFungus = new JRadioButton("Fungus");                

                rdoBtnPlant.setSelected(true);

                //Create a group of Radio Buttons
                ButtonGroup plantSelection = new ButtonGroup();
                plantSelection.add(rdoBtnPlant);
                plantSelection.add(rdoBtnFlower);
                plantSelection.add(rdoBtnHerb);
                plantSelection.add(rdoBtnWeed);
                plantSelection.add(rdoBtnFungus);
                JLabel plantSelectLabel = new JLabel("Please select from the following plants to add below: ");
                plantSelectLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", 20, 20));

                //Add radio buttons to contentPane
                add(plantSelectLabel);
                add(rdoBtnPlant);
                add(rdoBtnFlower);
                add(rdoBtnWeed);
                add(rdoBtnHerb);
                add(rdoBtnFungus);

                rdoBtnPlant.addActionListener(new RadioHandler());
                rdoBtnFlower.addActionListener(new RadioHandler());
                rdoBtnHerb.addActionListener(new RadioHandler());
                rdoBtnWeed.addActionListener(new RadioHandler());
                rdoBtnFungus.addActionListener(new RadioHandler());
                JLabel clrLabel = new JLabel("Enter Color:");

                JTextField txtColor = new JTextField("",15);

                JLabel plantIdentity = new JLabel("Enter Name:");

                JTextField txtName = new JTextField("",15);
                JLabel idLabel = new JLabel("Enter ID:");

                JTextField txtPlantID = new JTextField("", 15);

                plantPanel1.add(clrLabel);
                plantPanel1.add(txtColor);
                plantPanel1.add(plantIdentity);
                plantPanel1.add(txtName);
                plantPanel1.add(idLabel);
                plantPanel1.add(txtPlantID);
                add(plantPanel1);

                //Create CheckBoxes for Boolean value representations (0 and 1 / True or False)
                JLabel traits = new JLabel("Traits:");
                isPoisonous = new JCheckBox("Poisonous");
                isEdible = new JCheckBox("Edible");
                isMedicinal = new JCheckBox("Medicinal");
                isNicelyFlavored = new JCheckBox("Nice Flavor");
                isSeasonal = new JCheckBox("Seasonal");
                hasThorns = new JCheckBox("Thorny");
                smellsNice = new JCheckBox("Smells Nice");
                isPoisonous.setEnabled(false);
                isEdible.setEnabled(false);
                isMedicinal.setEnabled(false);
                isNicelyFlavored.setEnabled(false);
                isSeasonal.setEnabled(false);
                hasThorns.setEnabled(false);
                smellsNice.setEnabled(false);
                plantPanel2.add(traits);
                plantPanel2.add(isPoisonous);
                plantPanel2.add(isEdible);
                plantPanel2.add(isMedicinal);
                plantPanel2.add(isNicelyFlavored);
                plantPanel2.add(isSeasonal);
                plantPanel2.add(hasThorns);
                plantPanel2.add(smellsNice);

                add(plantPanel2);



                btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
                btnRemove = new JButton("Remove");
                btnSort = new JButton("Sort");
                btnFilter = new JButton("Filter");
                btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
                btnAdd.addActionListener(new ButtonHandlerAdd());
                plantPanel3.add(btnAdd);
                plantPanel3.add(btnRemove);
                plantPanel3.add(btnSort);
                plantPanel3.add(btnFilter);
                plantPanel3.add(btnClear);
                plantSummary = new JTextArea(10,20);
                plantSummary.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                plantSummary.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.PLAIN, 20));

                plantSummary.setEditable(false);
                plantSummary.setVisible(true);


                scrollPane = new JScrollPane(plantSummary);
                scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                plantPanel4.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


                add(plantPanel3);
                add(plantPanel4);
                setSize(900, 600);

                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setVisible(true);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new PlantGUIDriverFinalAssignment();
        }

        private void addPlant() {
        //Add a plant that is specified by the user 

            plantName = txtName.getText();            
            plantColor = txtColor.getText();            
            plantID = txtPlantID.getText();
            Plant thePlant = new Plant(plantColor, plantID, plantName);
            plantList.add(thePlant);
            plantSummary.append(thePlant.toString());
    }

        private void addFlower() {
        //Add a plant that is specified by the user
        String flowerName;
        String flowerColor;
        String flowerID;
        boolean scentType;

        boolean isThorny;                
                flowerName = txtName.getText();
                flowerColor = txtColor.getText();
                flowerID = txtPlantID.getText();
                isThorny = hasThorns.isSelected();               
                scentType = smellsNice.isSelected();
                Flower theFlower = new Flower(flowerColor, flowerID, flowerName, scentType, isThorny);
                plantList.add(theFlower);
                plantSummary.append(theFlower.toString());

    }



    class RadioHandler implements ActionListener {



        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Plant")) {

                        isPoisonous.setEnabled(false);
                        isEdible.setEnabled(false);
                        isMedicinal.setEnabled(false);
                        isNicelyFlavored.setEnabled(false);
                        isSeasonal.setEnabled(false);
                        hasThorns.setEnabled(false);
                        smellsNice.setEnabled(false);

            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Fungus")) {
                        isPoisonous.setEnabled(true);
                        isEdible.setEnabled(false);
                        isMedicinal.setEnabled(false);
                        isNicelyFlavored.setEnabled(false);
                        isSeasonal.setEnabled(false);
                        hasThorns.setEnabled(false);
                        smellsNice.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Weed")) {
                        isPoisonous.setEnabled(true);
                        isEdible.setEnabled(true);
                        isMedicinal.setEnabled(true);
                        isNicelyFlavored.setEnabled(false);
                        isSeasonal.setEnabled(false);
                        hasThorns.setEnabled(false);
                        smellsNice.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Flower")) {
                        hasThorns.setEnabled(true);
                        smellsNice.setEnabled(true);
                        isPoisonous.setEnabled(false);
                        isMedicinal.setEnabled(false);
                        isSeasonal.setEnabled(false);
                        isNicelyFlavored.setEnabled(false);
                        isEdible.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Herb")) {
                        isPoisonous.setEnabled(false);
                        isEdible.setEnabled(false);
                        isMedicinal.setEnabled(true);
                        isNicelyFlavored.setEnabled(true);
                        isSeasonal.setEnabled(true);
                        hasThorns.setEnabled(false);
                        smellsNice.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

    }

    class ButtonHandlerAdd implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Add Button Clicked!");
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add") && rdoBtnPlant.isSelected()) {                
                addPlant();

            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add") && rdoBtnFlower.isSelected()) {
                addFlower();
            }

        }
    }

   /* class TextFieldVariable implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("TextFields listening");
            plantColor = txtColor.getText();
            plantID = txtPlantID.getText();
            plantName = txtName.getText();

        }
    }*/
}
```

Here is the Plant Class in case if you are wondering:

```
public class Plant {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String color;

    public Plant() {
        this.id = "";
        this.name = "";
        this.color = "";
    }

    public Plant(String plantColor, String plantID, String plantName) {
        this.id = plantID;
        this.color = plantColor;
        this.name = plantName;
    }

    public void setID(String plantID) {
        this.id = plantID;
    }

    public void setColor(String plantColor) {
        this.color = plantColor;
    }

    public void setName(String plantName) {
        this.name = plantName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "This plant's name is " + this.getName() + " with a color of: " + this.getColor() +
                " with a unique ID of: " + this.getID();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherPlant) {
        if (otherPlant == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!Plant.class.isAssignableFrom(otherPlant.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        final Plant other = (Plant) otherPlant;

        if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(this.color.equals(other.color))) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!(this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

I don't know why the code is getting the runtime error. Where am I going wrong? Thanks. Apologies in advance if the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Create a [mcve]. You will probably find your own mistake in the process.

Comment: You should first search this site for similar problems, here [search on NullPointerException](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java&oq=si&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+nullpointerexception), then use the answers to the best question to help you solve your all too common problem.

Comment: The first hit has your answer: The heuristic for NullPointerExceptions is almost always the same: You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: So, what is happening on the critical line, line `PlantGUIDriverFinalAssignment.java:170`?

Comment: Ah, I see -- you're shadowing the `txtPlantID` field and many other fields. This is where you re-declare the field as a local variable in a constructor or init method, and initialize the re-dclared local variable leaving the field in the class as null. The solution is: don't do this, don't re-declare the field as a local variable. Note that this has nothing to do with Swing and all to do with basic Java practices.

Comment: [maybe a better duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551033/java-swing-jbutton-componnent-nullpointerexception)

Comment: Oh my gosh, I'm so stupid a total disgrace to all CS majors out there. It was because when I declared my ArrayList, it was indeed null. Thanks!

Comment: It's not the only field that's null.

Comment: You are right, I figured out the rest though. Like I said earlier, I'm a disgrace to all CS people out there :-D. Hopefully in the real Workforce I won't literally embarrass myself like this.